# switching databases in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am trying to use / change the database for different organizations / users. In master database, I have db_name for different organizations, I am using  the following code to store the db_name in session.

```
$condition = "subdomain =" . "'" . $data['subdomain'] . "' AND " . "status =1";

$this->db->select('id, db_name');
$this->db->from('sublogin');
$this->db->where($condition);
$this->db->limit(1);

$db_name = $this->db->get()->row()->db_name;

// SET db_name for session
$this->session->set_userdata('db_name', $db_name);
```

in another model, switch the database

```
$db_name = $this->session->userdata('db_name');
$this->db->db_select($db_name);
```

Its working on localhost but not on my live server, it gives error:

> A Database Error Occurred
>   Error Number: 1146
>   Table 'db694230824.users' doesn't exist

I tried to echo the current database and it says the database is not changed.

```
echo $this->db->database;
die();
```

Comment: Does your database user have the correct permissions to be able to access both databases?

Comment: let me check the permissions.

Comment: Did you have any luck?

Comment: no, the support will reply in 48 hours. Its working fine on my localhost, so I think its permission problem as you mentioned. so, I need to wait for them.

Comment: I am very unlucky here, all of my questions goes with no answer and with (-) negative points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1 solution.**

You can work with multiple databases like this:

```
$this->db = $this->load->database('default', TRUE);
$this->anotherDb = $this->load->database('anotherDb ', TRUE);
```

Or if you assign the codeigniter super-object:

```
public function __construct($params) {

   $this->CI = & get_instance();
   $this->CI->db = $this->CI->load->database('default', TRUE);
   $this->CI->anotherDb = $this->CI->load->database('anotherDb', TRUE);
}
```

**2 solution**

It was working earlier, not 100% sure if it still works, but looks like this bug still exist in CI.
Just add 1 line of code at simple_query function in /system/database/DB_driver.php file:

```
public function simple_query($sql)
{
    if ( ! $this->conn_id)
    {
        $this->initialize();
    }

    $this->db_select(); // add this
    return $this->_execute($sql);
}
```

It should allow you use other databases in models like this:

```
$this->anotherDb = $this->load->database('anotherDb', true);
```

Don't forget to add other's DBs CONNECTIVITY SETTINGS in /application/config/database.php file in similar way as you have with your default db:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    ...
);

$db['anotherDb'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    ...
);
```

[CodeIgniter » Docs » Database Reference » Connecting to your Database](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/connecting.html#connecting-to-multiple-databases)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It will be my second option, as the $this->db_select(mydb); is working fine for me in localhost. I am waiting for hosting company to reply and give permission to dbuser on other databases too.

Comment: still waiting for hosting company. using this solution I will be needed to define every database, and my application will have more than 1 database, may be 100. so, I think I must use db_select().

Comment: yeah, 2nd solution could be more comfortable and will provide flexible options.

though, all depends on design of your application. in some cases 1 solution could be better.

Comment: I don't want to hardcode my database name, because there will be more databases in my application. 1 database for 1 school.

Comment: implemented the 1st solution, and also used dynamic database_names.